# Java not returning array object from list.toArray()

Tags: java, arrays, json, list

I have a `movie` class
That has a `private List<String> reviews = new ArrayList<String>();`

On the constructor I set

```
public Movie()
{
    this.reviews.add("");
}
```

When I try to add it to a `JSON` object as so,

```
JSONObject.put("reviews", this.reviews.toArray(new String[reviews.size()]));
```

I checked the `JSON` file and it return `"reviews":[Ljava.lang.String;@5cad8086]`

What is happening here? I want to put an Array of reviews into the field "reviews" like `{"reviews" : ["somestring1", "somestring2"]}`

Comment: What is `JSONObject`?

Comment: It is a JSONObject where the put method accept the field & value as arguments respectively

Comment: are you creating JSON file, or you are using some library?

Comment: From what library? Which version of it?

Comment: Why was there downvote on this anyway?

Comment: Do you know what `[Ljava.lang.String;@5cad8086]` represents? Have you at least looked that up?

Comment: It is storing the address of the array right but I have no idea why, hence the question

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json-simple apparently doesn't support adding array types directly to a `JSONObject`. When rendering the `JSONObject` to a `String`, it simply calls `toString` on its values (`JSONObject` is a `HashMap`).

As such, you're seeing the default `String` result of invoking `toString` on an array type. See

- [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

The most appropriate solution with json-simple is to create a `JSONArray` object from your `List` and add that

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.addAll(reviews);
JSONObject.put("one", array);
```

assuming `JSONObject` is a variable that references a `JSONObject` object.

---

I'll end this with my opinion that json-simple is a terrible JSON parser/generator library. There are much better alternatives in Gson, Jackson, and even org.json.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use this :

`Arrays.toString(this.reviews.toArray(new String[reviews.size()]));`

Comment: This seems to generate `"reviews":"[myString]"` Instead of `"reviews":[{"myReviewString1"}, {myReviewString2}]`

Comment: @MaTaKazer What you just posted is invalid json.

Comment: I wanted something like `{"reviews" : ["somestring1", "somestring2"]}`